# Datagridview execute code on change of the column combo box value

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I am trying to reload the datagridview on change of the combobox value in on of that datagridview columns. I know how to do the reload, but I am having trouble triggering the action. Should I be looking for value change in this particular cell or is there a change in comobobox action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically use ComboBox_TextChanged events and you can use those within a datagridview as well, as you add them:

comboBox1.TextChanged += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      // Do Whatever
}

Answer (score 0):

Do a DataGridView1.Refresh() on the combobox change event.

Comment: Shouldn't it be column combobox change event? I can't find one. Can you please give me the name of the exact event. I think I could do that by cell value change, but I thought there is easier way to do it buy getting the column combo box change event.

Comment: If you want to get the event of an element change, right click on that element, and click properties, and click on the "lightning" button, you will see a whole list of events. And when you see the column combo box value change, double click on that, and it will generate the event function you needed.

Comment: Yes, that's good for regular combo box. But this combo box is inside a column in a data grid view, so I can't just select it. I have to select the whole data grid view.

Comment: Is it of datatype DataGridViewComboBoxCell or DataGridViewComboBoxcolumn?

Comment: Did you figure out the solution?

Comment: Working on it. I might tie it into another part of the project.